# How can I add directional friction like asteroids with SPEED and DIRECTION?

Tags: physics, lerp

I'm trying to make asteroids, and right now I'm setting the direction based on the mouse angle, like so:

```
let r = Math.atan2(ct.mouse.x-this.x, ct.mouse.y-this.y) * 180 / Math.PI;

this.rotation = Math.round(r - 180);    
this.direction = Math.round(r - 90);
```

which works more like a car, as soon as you turn, you are moving in the new direction at the same speed.

but in asteroids it's more slippery, and the direction doesn't change immediately when you're thrusting, it's like it has to fight against the current direction and speed.

How can i change the direction and speed variables over time to reflect this? I don't have true physics available.

I'm in ct.js by the way, but this is a mostly general question.

Comment: If you're determined to parametrize your movement in polar coordinates, as a direction + speed, this is a bit more challenging. If you can change to working in cartesian coordinates, where your velocity is tracked in x and y, independent of the object's rotation, this becomes almost free. Is that a change your codebase can support?

Comment: Personally, I would try to lerp the the mouse input and camera follow functions first. If that doesn't work you can try lerping other values, it depending on your setup.

Comment: yeah most examples I see are just using XY velocity, so I guess I should use that

Comment: @formatc2013 careful, lerping controls can cause problems if your framerate isn't fixed.

Comment: You are going to need to implement some simple physics like in a free body diagram. Moving towards the mouse should be a force or acceleration, not an instant change in momentum. Friction to slow down without any input is also another force applied to the player. Every frame you should calculate the new velocity based on the current velocity plus the net force from that free body diagram.